# Change timezone text to Amsterdam

Tags: configuration

this may sound silly. But in the backend we have timezone set under configuration/general = W.Europe/Berlin. This is the same timezone as Amsterdam. Amsterdam is where our webstore is located. When I post a blog or update it is timestamped with x.y.z time @ W.Europe/Berlin ....  would like it to be W.Europe/Amsterdam.

Could I just look the string up in core config or another table and change it there? Or would I be breaking a lot of stuff? (I can image time is in the very core of a system)

Or can I add a timezone?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This string is, as far as I know, used for setting the PHP timezone as well.
Since you want to change how data is displayed I'd suggest "translating" it in the presentation layer, the PHTML files. This way it can't have any impact on the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a timezone is going to be pretty hairy because you'll have to inject the timezone not only into PHP's `Date` object but possibly also into Zend as a locale. I've done this for the Pirate Language pack and it requires a local Zend override - hardly optimal.

I would suggest that you translate the string either via translate.csv in your theme or in the javascript translator (insert a translate entry into `core_translate`).

Best of luck!